# Centrality measures and normalisation

Tags: graphs-and-networks

Are centrality measures normalised in *Mathematica 9*? Only `ClosenessCentrality` is normalised. How I can normalise other centrality measures notably `DegreeCentrality` and `BetweennessCentrality`?

```
g = GridGraph[{5, 5}];
ClosenessCentrality[g] // Short
BetweennessCentrality[g] // Short
DegreeCentrality[g] // Short
```

> {0.24,0.282353,0.3,0.282353,0.24,0.282353<14>>,0.24,0.282353,0.3,0.282353,0.24}
>   {2.6881,17.2071,21.5429,17.2071,<<18>>,21.5429,17.2071,2.6881}
>   {2,3,3,3,2,3,4,4,4,3,3,4,4,4,3,3,4,4,4,3,2,3,3,3,2}

Comment: Please give a minimal example of `Graph`, of `DegreeCentrality` and the desired output.

Comment: OK @Öskå I give the example of tutorial

Comment: How about using `Normalize`? Or `Rescale`?

Comment: @DuralAkata  Öskå asked you to explain what output *you want* (*desired* output), not to post the output that Mathematica produces.  In particular, explain what you mean by "normalization" in this context.  What you might assume to be a generally known meaning of this term may not actually be standard outside of your field.

Comment: In fact in literature we can calculate unnormalised centralities indicators and we can calculate these normalised centralities indicators vary between 0 and 1 and I think in mathematica just ClosenessCentrality is normalised because vary between 0 and 1

Comment: Any idea for normalisation? it is right to use Normalize function to obtain normalised indicatore